# Deadlocking in Java (with an example)

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I'm reading a topic on Java concurrency, and here's what the author writes:

Because addListener(), removeListener(), and updateProgress() are all synchronized,
multiple threads can call them without stepping on one another’s toes. But
a trap lurks in this code that could lead to deadlock even though there’s only
a single lock in use.
The problem is that updateProgress() calls an alien method—a method it knows
nothing about. That method could do anything, including acquiring another
lock. If it does, then we’ve acquired two locks without knowing whether we’ve
done so in the right order. As we’ve just seen, that can lead to deadlock.

**Could you please explain, how can we obtain two locks in the wrong order, if we always acquire the first lock in the first place (as the method updateProgress is synchronized!!), meaning the second from two locks the author is speaking about will always be acquired in the second place?**

```
class Downloader extends Thread {
    private InputStream in;
    private OutputStream out;
    private ArrayList<ProgressListener> listeners;

    public Downloader(URL url, String outputFilename) throws IOException {
        in = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        out = new FileOutputStream(outputFilename);
        listeners = new ArrayList<ProgressListener>();
    }

    public synchronized void addListener(ProgressListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public synchronized void removeListener(ProgressListener listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    private synchronized void updateProgress(int n) {
        for (ProgressListener listener : listeners)
            listener.onProgress(n);

    }

    public void run() {
        int n = 0, total = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try {
            while ((n = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, n);
                total += n;
                updateProgress(total);
            }
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have two instances of `Downloader`, call them `dlA` and `dlB`. You also have one listener, which simply removes itself from both of those downloaders, and which is initially attached to both downloaders:

```
Downloader dlA = new Downloader(...);
Downloader dlB = new Downloader(...);

ProgressListener listener = new ProgressListener() {
  @Override
  public void onProgress(int n) {
    dlA.removeListener(this);
    dlB.removeListener(this);
  }
}

dlA.addListener(listener);
dlB.addListener(listener);
```

Okay, now what happens when two threads call `updateProgress` at the same time, one on `dlA` and the other on `dlB`?

```
thread1: dlA.updateProgress(1)      thread2: dlB.updateProgress(1)
         gets lock on dlA                    gets lock on dlB
         calls listener.onProgress(1)        calls listener.onProgress(1)
           calls dlA.removeListener(this)      calls dlA.removeListener(this)
             succeeds                            tries to get lock on dlA
           calls dlB.removeListener              (stuck until thread1 finishes
             tries to get lock on dlB             dlA.updateProgress)
             (stuck until thread2 finishes
              dlB.updateProgress)
```

There you go, deadlock!

The problem is that the listener code can do *anything it wants*, including acquiring locks (directly or indirectly), and that code is executed while your thread keeps the hold on `this`. The moment you don't have complete control over what locks are acquired, you open yourself up to a possibility of deadlock.

Comment: Thank you. "Listener invokes" actions happen from separate threads (i.e. thread 3, thread 4 in parallel with threads 1,2) or it happens within the onProgress() method of the listener?

Comment: Well, both. It happens within the `onProgress()` method of the listener, but remember that there are _two_ listeners, each of which has its onProgress invoked on a separate thread. `dlA`'s listener is invoked on thread1 (via the listener.onProgress(n) call in dlA.updateProgress, which was invoked on thread1), and `dlB`'s listener is invoked on thread2. But you could even accomplish this with just _one_ listener, which removes itself from both dlA and dlB.

Comment: I updated the answer a bit to show how it can happen with just a single listener.

Comment: Thank you, brilliant answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `listener.onProgress()` is outside the scope of your lock.  If it tries to obtain a lock on something that is already blocked, but that something then needs to get a lock on your object, a deadlock can occur.